# Freedos Blinking Cursor after install

Tags: dos

Just went through the FreeDOS install and installed to `C:\` from a CD drive.

After boot, I get just the blinking cursor.

How can I get it to boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the command `prompt $P$G` and see if the cursor prompt changes.

If you already get a prompt like `c:\` or `c:\dos` then clarify your question with more information.